# Get sum of column with condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question that I cannot find answer to.

Basically, I have two columns:

```
variable 10  || 14  || 18 || 20 || 29  || 38 || 39  || 41 || 46  ...
values   857 || 736 || 84 || 1  || 362 || 74 || 183 || 77 || 944 ...
```

I want to output the sum of all the values in each variable with 10s `(10, 14, 18)` then 20s `(20, 29)` then 30s `(38, 39)` so on and so forth.

How would I construct the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
select variable div 10, sum(values) 
  from myTable
 group by variable div 10
```

result (assuming your columns are named `var` and `val` now:

```
mysql> select var div 10, sum(val) from my  group by var div 10;
+------------+----------+
| var div 10 | sum(val) |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |     1677 | 
|          2 |      363 | 
|          3 |      257 | 
|          4 |     1021 | 
+------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```